# How to restrict "Publisher" by Azure Policy

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, policy, azure-policy

we have hard time, because we are trying to restrict specific "Publishers" by Azure Policy but we find only how to restrict a "Type". Isnt there a noble soul, who know, how to help us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a policy like the one below to restrict compute resources from a specific publisher -

```
    {
      "policyRule": {
        "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.Compute/imagePublisher",
              "match": "[parameters('NotAllowedImage')]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "Deny"
        }
      },
      "parameters": {
        "NotAllowedImage": {
          "type": "String",
          "metadata": {
            "displayName": "Not Allowed  Image",
            "description": "Not Allowed Image for Virtual Machine/Compute"
          }
        }
      },
      "metadata": {
        "category": "Compute"
      }
    }
```

When you assign this image to a subscription or a resource group then at the time you will be asked to enter a value for the image name you would like to restrict. Save the assignment.

Now once you create a vm/compute resource from the denied image publisher then it would fail the validation step as the policy would not allow to create such vm/compute resource.